# "If you have time, say this"

Tags: halacha, tefilla, time, prayer-book, korbanos-ketores-prayers

I have seen in many siddurim, mainly in korbonos, the phrase "if you have time, add this parsha".

How do you know if you have time?  It seems obvious that if adding it would make you miss zman tefila, you don't have time.

If it's already past zman tefila and you're relying on davening before chatzos, do you have time?  If it's well before zman tefila but adding this would make you late to help your wife at home, do you have time?

Comment: (FWIW I don't remember ever seeing that.) Another option to consider is that it means "if saying this won't delay you sufficiently to prevent you from saying X with the congregation", where X is _amida_ or something else.

Answer (score 3):

[O Ch 66 (7) MB 35](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=197). As per @msh210's comment, quoting from the middle of the MB, "Ideally one should start the שמונה עשרה together with the קהל and the ש‏"ץ". So if saying extra korbonos etc. means you can't do that, then don't say them.

Regarding פסוקי דזמרא and skipping them for the same purpose, see [O Ch 52 (1) MB 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=153&hilite=) regarding the priority of the tehillim.

Comment: But it doesn't say this before most chapters of pesukei dizimra

Comment: Is your recent edit directed at my comment? I don't see how it addresses it. Obviously _lechatchila_ one should arrive early enough to say whatever parts of pesukei dizimra and korbanot are prescribed.

Comment: I agree with @DoubleAA - it's clear that there is a distinction being made between these parshiyos and the rest of korbonos, so it seems to me that there is more at work here than the basic rule of what one skips to keep up with the congregation.

Comment: @DoubleAA Point taken.