# Which parts of Shacharit are skippable, optional, or not universally recited?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer

A newcomer to traditional Jewish prayer is often confused or overwhelmed by modern siddurim, in particular those of Artscroll, which contain a number of prayers that are required, and not said by most people. People often are unsure which parts they can or should skip. Lack of clarity about this issue can lead to transgression. For example, some may be of the mistaken impression that [reciting korbanos](http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/11/korbanot/) is not required (while in fact at least the Tamid section is an obligation).

For these reasons, I thought it would be useful for many people to list the following parts of Shacharit, and ask for each of them, whether it is A) said by all Orthodox Jewish men as part of Shacharit, B) said by most Orthodox Jewish men, C) said by some, D) if it is said only or particularly by a certain group or groups, then name that group, and E) if the part is considered an obligation, and if so, the source for the fact that it is an obligation.

This list is in order of appearance in the Artscroll siddur. Parts that are clearly required (morning blessings, Baruch SheAmar, etc, are omitted).

1 Reishit Chochma

2 Barchi Nafshi

3 Mah Yakar Chasdcha Elokim

4 Mah tovu

5 Yigdal

6 Akeidah

7 L'olam y'he adam yrey shamayim

8 Ribon kol haolamim

9 Aval anachnu

10 L'fichach anachnu

11 First paragraph of the Shma (as part of the morning blessings)

12 Atah hu ad shelo nivra haolam

13 Korbanos (other than Tamid)

14 Mizmor Shir Chanukat haHaBayit

15 Hodu LaHashem Kiru Vishmo

16 Yehi kavod Hashem l'olam

17 Baruch Hashem l'olam, amen v'amen

18 Vayvarech David et Hashem l'einei kol kahal

19 Atah hu Hashem l'vadecha

20 Shirat HaYam

21 Yehi ratzon milfanecha (after oseh shalom after the end of the Amidah)

22 Song of the day

Comment: So... you're taking a survey?

Comment: No. People should answer if they feel like they know the answer to my question -- that is, whether everyone says each of the 22, whether some people do, whether they're considered an obligation and according to whom, etc.

Comment: "For these reasons, I thought it would be useful for many people to list the following parts [...]" This implies that you're not looking for a "correct" answer, but for a variety responses (many people) based upon their observations and experiences. If you're looking for someone to compile a single answer with an authoritative list, I suggest you reword your question.

Comment: IMO - This is a LONG list! I recommend, perhaps, just asking which parts of Shacharit (you may want to narrow it down to a specific nusach, if applicable in your question) are required halachically (narrow down, say based on Talmud, or whatever criteria).

Comment: Could make a good community wiki if people want to edit in what they know.  If we do it as a wiki, I would recommend adding in Barchu, etc noting "everyone says" in the interest of completeness.

Comment: Where is your source that reading Tamid is compulsory? And if so, do you have to say Birkat Kohanim as the Torah read after the blessing? Maybe you could recite the blessings over the Torah then Tamid as your Torah).

Comment: FWIW, the Yehi Ratzon after Amidah is included in most siddurim, at least inasmuch as the passuk of  "sheyibaneh" is concerned.

Comment: @CashCow See the link

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Maybe so, but this doesn't mean it's compulsory -- perhaps only some recite it? For example, I think most siddurim have mah yakar, but in the Koren Sachs siddur he says "some say" mah yakar, suggesting this is an optional practice.

Comment: Mah Yakar is a different case. I have not seen a note in any siddur saying that that particular yehi ratzon is optional. Then again, the best practice would likely be to do a systematic analysis of the Rambam, the Machzor Vitry, and the other rishonic siddurim.

Comment: @CashCow You can say any Torah you want after the blessings.

Comment: I don't agree with the reasons for putting this question on hold. There should not be too many answers, because few people have enough experience and knowledge to be able to answer all the questions. A good answer would not be too long, because all it would need is one sentence or so for each of the 22. For example, the answer to each of them could be something like this: 1) Everyone says this, and it is an obligation (see Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim XYZ:AB); or 2) Many say this, but it appears to be a optional, as it is not in Shulchan Aruch or its commentaries, and is not in all siddurim.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31850/759

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65309

Answer (score 2):

In most German Siddurim, one will not find Parashat haAkeidah within birchot hashachar. According to an exchange I had with Mori Doweedh Ya3aqob, it is also omitted in nusach Teiman. According to him, it is a kabbalistic insertion of relatively late origin, and should be omitted.

In The *Mesoras Harav* machzor by Artscroll, there is a note relating that R' Soloveitchik held that one should not recite Ps. 30 (Chanukah Habayit) before Baruch She'amar, based on the opinion of the Gr"a. This was also the practice in Germany.

Furthermore, in the R' Wiesenthal's *Sefas Yisroel*, he mentions that one should not split up Vayivarech David and V'charot imo habrit, unless there is a bris. Based on this, we may derive that one should say both the passage from Divrei Hayamim and the one from Nechemia (18 and 19 in the OP).

Comment: Thanks. I've also heard R' Soloveitchik was opposed to saying Yigdal.

Answer (score 0):

Just picking on one of those: first paragraph of Shema in the B'rachot section.

I read (sorry don't have the source) that it is better not to recite this if you know the congregation will reach K'riyat Sh'ma by the z'man.

And if they are not going to you should recite all 3 paragraphs in time, not just the first one.

That is because it is preferable to recite Kriyat Sh'ma with its b'rachot and then to commence the Amidah immediately after Ga'al Yisrael without any interruption.

Given the "disputes" about how much of the Sh'ma one needs to recite to fulfil the mitzvah, according to those who state the first paragraph, you will have already fulfilled the mitzvah and thus the second time (when said with the b'rachot) will not actually be the point of fulfillment (albeit you are doing it then in its best possible way, that is, reciting all 3).

(Those who have the opinion that the mitzvah is fulfilled with just the first line: I don't know how they manage this situation).

Comment: according to R' Rallis Wiesenthal's siddur, only the first passuk and ברוך שם are required, even when there is a chance of missing zman (e.g. when piyutim are said).

Comment: Re your last line: they just say "Shema Yisrael" and leave off the end of the verse.

Comment: The Artscroll just says to have intention to not fulfill his obligation when saying that part.