# What prayers are obligatory on a daily basis? What prayers are obligatory on Shabbat? And who decides what's actually obligatory?

Tags: tefilla, halacha-theory, prayer-book

When you go through a siddur you see lots of prayers, but never a mention of what's actually obligatory. Having seen the Rambam siddur, it seems like we have a looooot more prayers now, but are they actually obligatory? Which ones are obligatory, and who makes that decision now that there isn't a Sanhedrin anymore?

Comment: I was talking about this about an hour ago. At least according to some poskim, Pesukei d'zimrah are not required, particularly when pressed for time, nor is siyum tefillah. This was his p'sak from his rav, yours may differ.

Comment: On another note, the Rambam's siddur is a bit weird. A friend of mine wonders whether Teimanim received the siddur from him or he from them. Sa'adia Gaon also has a short seder tefillah. (Ashkenazim to this day have a shorter tefillah than Sephardim FWIW.)

Comment: there is an obligation to say shma and to cry out to hashem in some form. According to some, that form is the amida http://israel.aish.com/smicha/RavCableSugyos/HilchosTfilah/Review%20Sheet%20for%20The%20Essential%20Obligation%20to%20Daven.doc

Comment: The minimal pesukei d'zimra is baruch she'amar, ashrei and yishtabach. On a Shabbat one should preferably recite Nishmat too.